# Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to add a REST datasource to my Apollo Server.
I created a class which extends RESTDataSource which contains all the API requests.
When trying to call the login method from my GraphQL resolver code the error is thrown

How can I fix this?

I already tried:
Binding the login and fetch method in the API class constructor

this.login = this.login.bind(this);
this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this);

calling the login method from the constructor

RESTDataSource class

```
class API extends RESTDataSource {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.baseURL = URL;

            this.login = this.login.bind(this);
            this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this);
            console.log(this.fetch);
            console.log(this.login);

        }
        initialize(config) {
            //config can store different information
            //the current user can be stored in config.context for easy  access
            this.context = config.context;

        }

        async login(username, password) {
            return this.post(`/`, {
                "id": 1
            }, {
                "method": "authenticate"
            }, {
                params: {
                    "user": username,
                    "password": password
                },
                "jsonrpc": "2.0"
            })
        }
    }
```

Here's the index.js apollo server 'setup' file:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    dataSources: () => {
        return {
            managementDatabase: new ManagementDatabase(),
            API: new API() //was previously imported
        }
    }
});




server.listen().then(({
    url
}) => {
    log(`  Server ready at ${url}`)
})
```

Resolver file for GraphQL:

```
Query: {
        lessons: async (_source, _args, {
            dataSources
        }) => {
            const data = await dataSources.webuntisAPI.login(process.env.USER, process.env.PW);
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
}
```

Comment: What does ``console.log(this.fetch);`` show in the console?

Comment: The output is: `[Function: bound fetch]`

Comment: Which file and line number is throwing this error?

Comment: @kmoser the error is in `node_modules\\apollo-datasource-rest\\dist\\RESTDataSource.js:158:63)`. I also noticed something we printing `this` in the API class. There is a property called `httpFetch` which is undefined. When looking in to the restdatasource.js file the line that is throwing the error `const response = yield this.httpCache.fetch(request, {..` uses this.httpCache which is created like this in the constructor: `this.httpCache = new HTTPCache_1.HTTPCache(config.cache, this.httpFetch)` using httpFetch which(i guess) is undefined. But I have no clue why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the issue.
The problem was the method `initalize(config)` which is unnecessary in this case.
So to fix the issue, just remove the initalize method from your code

Answer (score 3):

I am writing this as an answer instead of comment because I don't have enough reps for that.
In the [tutorial on their official website](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/data-source/), this is mentioned.
[image: this is mentioned] Their tutorial runs fine when cloned and run, but the same isn't working when I implement it with overriding `initialize`. 
However, if I don't override it, it works as you've mentioned.
Are we doing it wrong? Or their docs need to be updated? Because the incorrect user being present on `context` is a serious case.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding http cache from `apollo-datasource-rest`

```
import { HTTPCache, RESTDataSource } from "apollo-datasource-rest";

@DataSourceService()
export class MyDataSource extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.httpCache = new HTTPCache(); // <---- This
    this.baseURL = "http://localhost:8080";
  }
```